# Finding the derivative of a composite function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So i'm working on this problem and am not sure if i'm applying the chain rule correctly because i'm arriving at what appears to be an incorrect answer.

Find $\frac{dw}{dx}$ if $u = \frac 12x^3$, $v=3(u + u^2$), and $w = \frac{1}{v^2}$

Am I right in thinking I should apply the chain rule?

$$f(g(h(x)))' = {f'(g(h(x)))} {g'(h(x))} {h'(x)}$$

Next I took the derivative of each of those functions to come up with:

$ \frac{d}{dv} = \frac{-2}{v^3}$, $\frac{d}{du} = 3(1 + 2u)$, and $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{3x^2}{2}$

Next I multiplied these derivatives together, simplified and substituted all v's and u's out with their original values until I just had x's, and then simplified more (used calculator for much of this instead of doing by hand)

Is that the correct approach and i'm messing up the algebra at the end, or did I mess up the application of the chain rule?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's exactly the correct approach, and the derivatives you computed are correct; if you get an incorrect final answer, check your algebraic manipulations. The only remark I'd add is on your notation. To be accurate, you should write $(f \circ g \circ h)'(x)$ rather than $f(g(h(x)))'$. This is because you are differentiating the composite function $f \circ g \circ h$ and evaluating it at the point $x$ (The RHS of that equation is correct though).

Also, $\dfrac{d}{dv} \neq \dfrac{-2}{v^3}$; strictly speaking this doesn't make sense. You should have written $\dfrac{dw}{dv} = \dfrac{-2}{v^3}$ instead, or $\dfrac{dw}{dv} \bigg|_{v} = \dfrac{-2}{v^3}$ to be more proper and indicate that you're evaluating at the point $v$, and likewise for the other derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for confirming I was on the right track and also for the correction on notation. As a beginner, I find the notation is a tricky thing to understand on its own.